# How to implement wait and notify on Scheduled thread in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a simple problem.
I have a scheduled thread that keeps on performs some actions on a list based on some conditions.
Now the problem is when the user enters '2' as his choice the scheduled thread has to wait and when the work is done then again the scheduled thread has to start it's process. This is like a simple producer and consumer problem. But I am confused with the Scheduler thread. Thanks in advance.
Here is the code:

```
package sample;

public class Sample {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        Parallel p = new Parallel();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(p, 0, 1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        while (true) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            switch (br.read()) {
                case 1:
                    newOrder();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    replace();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    public static void newOrder() {
        System.out.println("New Order ");
    }

    public static void replace() {
        System.out.println("Replace");
        // pause the scheduled thread 
        /*
           perform actions on the list

         */

        // notify the scheduled thread again
    }
}
```

**My Parallel thread class:**

```
package sample;

    public class Parallel implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Inside thread");
            //do operations on list
        }
    }
```

The problem is, whenever user enters '2' then the List will be updated. Mean while the scheduler thread keeps on updating the list. It me remove an element by iterating over it. This scenario is causing too much lag when multiple users enter '2'. And every thread acts upon the list update it and at the same time Scheduler thread is updating the list. I cannot make the scheduler thread stop because it has to do the work continuously but when user enters '2' what can I do to make the scheduler thread to pause until the user operation completes?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:  Let the scheduled task run all the time, but have it check a flag each time it wakes up.  If the flag is set one way, it does its usual work, but if the flag is set the other way it does nothing.

Then, the UI only has to set the value of the flag according to whether the task should "run" or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please elaborate on

- `has to wait` what for ?
- `the work is done` what should be done ?

A couple of notes :

1. Given you want to use a list from multiple threads, use a thread safe version, e.g. `Collections.synchronizedList()`
2. If you want a scheduled task to wait then do not use `scheduleAtFixedRate`, use `scheduleWithFixedDelay` instead.
3. Wait/notify naturally asks for a thread that is running continuously, not on a schedule.

Comment: Thank you Bax. The problem is, whenever user enters '2' then the List will be updated. Mean while the scheduler thread keeps on updating the list. It me remove an element by iterating over it. This scenario is causing too much lag when multiple users enter '2'. And every thread acts upon the list update it and at the same time Scheduler thread is updating the list. I cannot make the scheduler thread stop because it has to do the work continuously but when user enters '2' what can I do to make the scheduler thread to pause until the user operation completes?